# Интерфейc .Net приложения PSD

Tags: wpf, .net, xaml

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема... я даже, наверно, не знаю, как передать. Вообщем, есть программа, написанная с использованием WPF-XAML. У меня есть PSD интерфейса. Нужно натянуть.

Я понимаю, что мне нужно пройти эволюцию создания самого интерфейса в программном стиле. Отсюда вопрос - с чего начать? Каких людей искать? Или какую информацию читать или обрабатывать?

В интернете ничегошеньки не нашел... или может очень плохо искал, так как по сути саму задачу сформулировать не могу. Хотя про создание дизайна программы на WPF все пишут что легко.

Помогите, пожалуйста, советом.

Comment: А в чем собсна проблема? Программу сам писали? Она похожа на картинку? Нет? Что не похоже? Берите картинку и подменяйте.

Comment: Она написана с помощью MahApps.Metro... Возможно ли безболезненно удалить поддержку MahApps и внедрить свой дизайн... Это наверно сама проблема и есть - не знаю основ интеграции или же все писать на Xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в том интерфейсе, про который идет речь, по большей части - статические элементы, то есть это картинка, которую надо органически встроить в WPF, то разумно взять и поручить нарисовать ее дизайнеру не в PhotoShope'е, а в Illustrator'е, и сконвертировать ее из AI в XAML, а лучше - сразу рисовать в Expression Blend и сохранять в XAML. Затем этом XAML можно добавить в проект и, отталкиваясь от него, строить новый интерфейс.

Comment: Спасибо за тактичную наводку.. Скажите - вот ситуация поворачивается 5 точкой.. Что делать если дизайн уже в PSD. Не перерисовывать его в Illustrator правильно - есть какой нито конвертор? А то работа не из дешевых как бы...

Comment: Конвертера нет. PSD - это растр, а XAML - это вектор. Можно по необходимости разрезать картинку на части и использовать их в качестве фона отдельных элементов интерфейса.

Comment: Кстати Expression Blend может имортировать PSD - благодарю за наводку еще раз...